# tomcat filter url-pattern problem

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters, url-pattern

Hi
i have a tomcat server version 5.5.12 
and i am using a filter, the problem is that for some files the filter works and for other it doesnt, for example for the path **/software/files/generator.7z** it works but for path **/software/files/tokenizer.7z** it doesnt.
any idea what is the probelm ? 
thanks.

here is my filter tags in  the web.xml file.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>servlet.filters.LogFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>test-param</param-name>
    <param-value>This parameter is for testing.</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/software/files/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine. Apparently it was been requested from the browser cache instead of straight from the webserver.

Clean your browser cache, or do Ctrl+F5, or let the server add [response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) which instructs the browser to not cache the response.